# Find repeating tickets with more than one criteria

Tags: mysql, reporting

Lets say I have 2 tables: atms & tickets
each atm has many tickets.

ATM table:

```
ID    | NAME
-------------------------
A0109 | ATM 1
A0227 | ATM 2
etc.  | etc.
```

Ticket table:

```
ID    | ATM     | DATE_SUBMITTED        | PROBLEM_NAME     | STATUS
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | A0109   | 2014-02-01 17:00:00   | OUT_OF_PAPER     | CLOSED
2     | A0109   | 2014-02-08 17:00:00   | BLANK_SCREEN     | OPEN
etc.  | etc.    | etc.                  | etc.             | etc.
```

In general repeating rule (more than 1 ticket per ATM), I can use HAVING condition where COUNT(tickets.id) > 1 and GROUP them by ATM ID. But the problem is, the "repeating" criteria is different. The condition considered as repeating is any ATM that has **more than 2 tickets in 1 week** or **more than 3 tickets in 1 month**. How can I create SQL query for this problem?

Any help would be appreciated, 
thanks in advance

Comment: @Mihai what you propose is just not valid syntax.